# Dependency Injection not working with RabitMQ Service Bus with Azure Key Vault Value asp.net core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, rabbitmq, asp.net-core-mvc

I am configuring the service bus with dependency as below

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddSingleton<ServiceBusTransportOptions>(sp => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceBusTransportOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("ServiceBus").Value));
```

The value from the vault is as follows 
[image]

The configured value from the vault file is as below

**secrets.json**

```
{
"ServiceBus": "{\"Transport\": \"RabbitMq\",\"RabbitMq\": {\"Url\": \"rabbitmq://localhost\",\"Username\": \"guest\",\"Password\": \"guest\"}}"
}
```

**Model class**

```
public class ServiceBusTransportOptions : IOptions<ServiceBusTransportOptions>
    {
        public TransportType Transport { get; set; } = TransportType.AzureServiceBus;

        public AzureServiceBusTransportOptions AzureServiceBus { get; set; }

        public RabbitMqTransportOptions RabbitMq { get; set; }

        public ServiceBusTransportOptions Value => this;
    }
```

The value of  `var config = _.Resolve<IOptions<ServiceBusTransportOptions>>().Value;` is default not mapped with the vault value. So causing a null pointer experception

[image]

**containerBuilder.Extension.cs**

```
  public static void AddServiceBus(this ContainerBuilder builder,
            string applicationName,
            Action<IContainerBuilderConfigurator> configureMassTransitBuilder,
            Action<IComponentContext, IBusFactoryConfigurator> configureServiceBus)
        {
            builder.Register(
                    _ =>
                    {
                        var config = _.Resolve<IOptions<ServiceBusTransportOptions>>().Value;
                        switch (config.Transport)
                        {
                            case TransportType.AzureServiceBus:
                                return new AzureServiceBusConfigurationProvider(config.AzureServiceBus.Value) as
                                    IServiceBusConfigurationProvider;
                            case TransportType.RabbitMq:
                                return new RabbitMqServiceBusConfigurationProvider(config.RabbitMq.Value);
                            default:
                                return new InMemoryServiceBusConfigurationProvider() as
                                    IServiceBusConfigurationProvider;
                        }

                    })
                .As<IServiceBusConfigurationProvider>()
                .SingleInstance();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to manually deserialize. Bind to object model from configuration, and explicitly register the desired type

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("secret.json")
    .Build();
//"ConfigurationBinder.Gett<T>" method comes from
// Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll
ServiceBusTransportOptions options = configuration.GetSection("ServiceBus").Get<ServiceBusTransportOptions>();
services.AddSingleton(options);
```

And resolve as needed

```
//...
builder.Register(_ => {
    var config = _.Resolve<ServiceBusTransportOptions>();
    switch (config.Transport) {
        case TransportType.AzureServiceBus:
            return new AzureServiceBusConfigurationProvider(config.AzureServiceBus.Value) as
                IServiceBusConfigurationProvider;
        case TransportType.RabbitMq:
            return new RabbitMqServiceBusConfigurationProvider(config.RabbitMq.Value);
        default:
            return new InMemoryServiceBusConfigurationProvider() as
                IServiceBusConfigurationProvider;
    }
})
```

Comment: Since the value are not on appsetting.json they are in vault file for local its coming from secret.json

Comment: The values is somethings like this {
"ServiceBus": "{\"Transport\": \"RabbitMq\",\"RabbitMq\": {\"Url\": \"rabbitmq://localhost\",\"Username\": \"guest\",\"Password\": \"guest\"}}"
} So I need to deserilized it

Comment: @SanJaisy Which you can load into an IConfiguration

Comment: How can you please let me know. I am confuse

Comment: This work for me services.AddSingleton(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceBusTransportOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("ServiceBus").Value)); with builder of your code